# Can I display hidden text of a Microsoft Word document in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer

I have a Microsoft Word Document (`*.docx`) that contains hidden text. Can I display that text in LibreOffice Writer 5.1.4.2?

The LibreOffice wiki [suggests to enable the check mark at **View** > **Hidden Paragraphs**](https://help.libreoffice.org/index.php?title=Writer/Displaying_Hidden_Text&oldid=82400), but menu **View** > **Hidden Paragraphs** is already checked, so I guess this hidden text must be different from [hidden text created in LibreOffice Writer itself](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Hiding_Text).

The wiki further suggests

> - Double-click in front of the variable that you used to define the condition for hiding the text, and enter a different value for the variable.
> - Double-click in front of the hidden text field or the hidden paragraph field, and change the condition statement.

but I'm unsure how to locate any such variable in the document. Randomly doubleclicking in front of regions where I suspect hidden text might be didn't do anything except selecting the following non-hidden word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hidden text in a Word document was created by adding "hidden" effect to the font, then you should see it in Libre Office when non-printing characters are shown (press Ctrl + F10). If you still cannot see it, then go to: Tools → Options → LibreOffice Writer → Formatting Aids and verify that Hidden Text is checked.

Comment: The last step (enabling the checkmark for **Formatting Aids** (menu **Tools** → **Options**, section **LibreOffice Writer**) did the trick for my document. Thank you!